# On google-spreadsheet, is there a formula that equates to multiple if statements?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

In the below picture, the value of cell `B5` comes from a drop down menu of items.

I need a formula in C5 that will capture the following logic:

```
If B5 is 'Standard', C5 is 5.
If B5 is 'Square', C5 is 17.
If B5 is 'Large Landscape', C5 is 29.
etc...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution requires the function `vlookup()`

[image: screenshot of my solution with function vlookup]